# Send files, error when receiving

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qtnetwork

I'm trying to send many files using Qt Network but there is a problem.
My client works fine whith 5 files, but my server doesn't receive all files.
My server receives 2 files, and then, if I send a new file, the third file who was waiting arrives on the server...

Here is my code to receive files :

```
void Serveur::fichier_recu() {
 
    /* Permet de connaître la socket du client qui envoie le fichier */
    QTcpSocket *socket_client = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(sender());
 
    if(socket_client == 0) {
        return;
    }
 
    QDataStream in(socket_client);
    /* Si taille_message est vide, on regarde si on recois des données */
    if(taille_message == 0) {
        /* si les données sont < qu'un quint32 on quitte et attend jusqu'à ce qu'elles soit égales à un quint32 */
        if(socket_client->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint32)) {
            return;
        }
        in >> taille_message;
    }
 
    if(socket_client->bytesAvailable() < taille_message) {
        //Tout n'est pas encore arrivé
        return;
    }
 
    cout << "<Sytem> Reception d'un fichier." << endl;
 
    QByteArray donnees;
    QString nom_fichier;
    in >> nom_fichier >> donnees;
 
    QFile fichier("sauvegarde/" + nom_fichier);
    fichier.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    fichier.write(donnees);
    fichier.close();
 
    taille_message = 0;
 
    cout << "<System> Reception du fichier effectuee." << endl;
}
```

Comment: are you debugging with tcpdump, wireshark or similar tool for packet sniffing?

Comment: No but I will try one of them!

Comment: I learned something. I used RawCap (because Wireshark doesn't work on localhost) and I saw all my files! So the problem doesn't come from my client but from my server who doesn't receive last files...

Comment: wireshark can sniff on localhost as well

Comment: How big files? I'd recommend trying to read partial data into your own `QByteArray` buffer (and then using `QDataStream` on that), instead of trusting `QTcpSocket` to buffer it for you. IIRC, there's no guarantee on how much it will buffer for you. (And if this solves the problem, I'll be happy to write this as a proper answer.)

Comment: Not more than 20Ko... I don't understand tour solution, could you be more clear ?